# IOError: File not open for reading

Tags: python

I'm new to programming and I am trying to teach myself Python through http://learnpythonthehardway.org/.

In exercise 20, we are told to make a script like this:

```
from sys import argv

script, input_file = argv

def print_all(f):
    print f.read()

def rewind(f):
    f.seek(0)

def print_a_line(line_count, f):
    print line_count, f.readline()

current_file = open(input_file)

print "First let's print the whole file:\n"

print_all(current_file)

print "Now let's rewind, kind of like a tape."

rewind(current_file)

print "Let's print three lines:"

current_line = 1
print_a_line(current_line, current_file)

current_line = current_line + 1
print_a_line(current_line, current_file)

current_line = current_line + 1
print_a_line(current_line, current_file)
```

However, when I run it through the Terminal, it returned, "IOError: File not open for reading." I'm really confused and not sure about what it meant by "not open." Here's the full account of the traceback message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex20.py", line 18, in <module>
    print_all(current_file)
  File "ex20.py", line 6, in print_all
    print f.read()
IOError: File not open for reading
```

I checked that the file exists. Can someone please help? Thanks a lot!

Update:

I solved the problem by creating a separate folder, thus isolating the new .py and .txt files to a new folder by themselves. I'm wondering if the previous .py files played a role in this? I wrote a truncating script before as well, but it wouldn't make sense because I only executed the new python file.

Comment: Also, when you are describing an error, please show the full traceback (which will indicate on what line the error is occurring)

Comment: Check if the file **exists**. That can be a source of problems pretty often. Also, use try catch.

Comment: @Aleksandar: That would produce a `No such file or directory` error, not a `File not open for reading` one

Comment: Its working fine here. I am not getting any such error.

Comment: I checked my indentation and the file exists. I reproduced my traceback info here. Thanks!

Comment: @RanRag would that be a problem with my computer?

Comment: No it would be a problem with your script. Are you sure this example is **exactly** the same code you are running?

Comment: @jdi Yes I copied and pasted it to be sure. I checked it over as well.

Comment: @user1691278: I don't suppose. [This is what I tried](http://sprunge.us/GjBZ). Is this your expected output. Your rewind function doesn't work.

Comment: @user1691278 what is the content of the file? This might also play a role.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra Interestingly enough, whenever I tried to run my script, the text in the file would disappear when I open it afterwards.

Comment: You are somehow opening your file for `'w'` mode, and not the default `'r'` mode. Not sure how that could happen if your code is exactly as written above.